# sonar c++ plugin parser error

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I have a project which contains one cpp file and included few header files. Sonar squid sensor complains about parser error in the file, and I am getting the parser error messages in the output log with INFO statements.
After this when I get the number of lines of code from `Decorator context` of sonar it is giving me 1 line.
How can i make sure to skip the parser error, i tried

```
sonar.cxx.errorRecoveryEnabled=true
```

But still the error is displayed in log and i am getting the total lines as 1.
When ever there is a parser error in the files i am getting the value NCLOC = 1.0